# Specify Giveup/Failure Action

Tags: c#, http, polly, retry-logic

I am using [Polly](https://github.com/michael-wolfenden/Polly) to make HTTP requests and retry 5 attempts if the request fails.

Is it possible to specify an action when 5 attempts have failed and the policy gives up?

In the below code; when we have failed 5 times I know the user doesn't have internet so I want to display a messagebox saying 'App requires internet'. I can use a counter to count 5 fails but it would be nicer to use a Polly method.

```
var policy = Polly.Policy.Handle<Exception>().WaitAndRetryAsync(
   5,
   retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),
   (ex, span) =>
   {
       Mvx.Trace("Retried because of {0}", ex);
   }
);

await policy.ExecuteAsync(() => MakeRequestEx<T>(requestUrl, verb, accept, headers, baseAddress)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `ExecuteAndCapture`

```
var policyResult = await policy.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(
    () => MakeRequestEx<T>(requestUrl, verb, accept, headers, baseAddress)
).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

You can then inspect the `Outcome` of the `policyResult` to check whether the call failed and display a message.

see https://github.com/michael-wolfenden/Polly#post-execution-steps for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your approach let me try to describe them

#### Not all operations are idempotent

Based on your shared code I assume your `MakeRequestEx` function is generic enough to issue request with `GET` or `POST` verbs. If you blindly apply retry logic against any kind of request then you might end up with unwanted duplicates or irreversible side-effects.

That's why in order to use retry logic you should meet these criteria group:

- The potentially introduced observable impact is acceptable
- The operation can be redone without any irreversible side effect
- The introduced complexity is negligible compared to the promised reliability

Most of the time the `GET` operations are written in idempotent way, but the other (CRU) operations aren't. Please make sure that your downstream system support request de-duplication for all verbs if you want to use your policy + `MakeRequestEx` as it is.

#### Not all errors are transient

Based on your shared code you want to retry if an exception is thrown. The problem with this approach is that not all exceptions represent a transient/temporal issue.

If you re-execute an operation like `10/0` then you will always receive a `DivideByZeroException` no matter how many times you want to retry it. The same is true for http request. For example if the url is invalid then you would receive an `UrlFormatException`. If you re-do it N times it will be still an `UrlFormatException` because it is not a transient failure.

Most of the time it is sufficient to re-do http requests if you receive `HttpRequestException` or when the response status code is one of these: 408, 429 or 5XX.

---

#### Counting the retries

> when we have failed 5 times I know the user doesn't have internet so I want to display a messagebox saying 'App requires internet'

The retry policy's `Execute` and `ExecuteAsync` methods [work in the way](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry#how-polly-retry-works) that if the operation can't be successfully completed after N retries they throw the last attempt's exception.

So, if you wrap your `ExecuteAsync` with a `try`-`catch` block then you can be sure that all retries has failed when the execution flows into the `catch` block.

```
try
{
   await policy.ExecuteAsync(() => MakeRequestEx<T(...));
}
catch
{
   MessageBox.Show("Operation failed after 6 attempts");
}
```

In the message of the `MessageBox` I have written 6 attempts since you have configured your policy with 5 retries but there is also the initial (0th) attempt.

If you don't want to use `try`-`catch` block then you can use the `ExecuteAndCapture`/`ExecuteAndCaptureAsync` method. These method will not throw an exception if all retry attempts failed rather populate the `FinalException` property of the `PolicyResult` and sets the `Outcome` property to `Failure`.

```
var retryResult = await policy.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(() => MakeRequestEx<T(...));
if (retryResult.Outcome == Outcome.Failure)
    MessageBox.Show("Operation failed after 6 attempts");
```

If you would like to know how many retry attempts were issued then you need to use the `Context` object. The `ExecuteAsync`/`ExecuteAndCaptureAsync` are defined on the `AsyncPolicy` base class, so they are not specific to the retry policy that's why they are not exposing the issued retry attempts.

If you define some helper methods like this:

```
public static class ContextExtensions
{
    private static readonly string key = "RetryCount";

    public static void IncreaseRetryCount(this Context context)
    {
        var retryCount = GetRetryCount(context);
        context[key] = ++retryCount;    
    }

    public static int GetRetryCount(this Context context)
    {
        context.TryGetValue(key, out object count);
        return count != null ? (int)count : 0;
    }
}
```

then you can call

- the `IncreaseRetryCount` at each retry attempt
- the `GetRetryCount` after the execution of the policy

```
var policy = Polly.Policy
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(5,
       retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)),
       (ex, _, ctx) =>
       {
            Mvx.Trace("Retried because of {0}", ex);
            ctx.IncreaseRetryCount();
       });
```

```
var result = await policy.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(() => MakeRequestEx<T(...));
var outcome = result.Outcome == OutcomeType.Successful ? "completed" : "failed";
MessageBox.Show($"Operation has {outcome} after the initial attempt + {result.Context.GetRetryCount()} retry attempts");
```